# Window.parent.postmessage issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, token

So I am inside an external 3rd party application. When a notification appears, there is a link to our website(app), which is in the form of an iframe.  I need to speak directly to the parent window using window.parent.postmessage to get a handshake and our website(app) is supposed to have an event listener, but the parent window never sends an event back.  Is there anything apparently wrong with my code?

```
window.parent.postMessage({ "action": "Handshake" }, "*");  
Listener = function(event) {
     for (var type in event.data) {
         var payload = event.data[type];
         window.alert("Payload: " + payload + " type: " + type);
         switch (type) {
            case "token":

                var token = payload;
                update = {
                    ui: {
                        alert: true

                    },
                    validToken: token
                };
//so on and so forth
```

I'm thinking that there could be a possibility where when the notification appears, it creates another window and the iframe is in there with our website.  Because of that when I call the parent is it just calling the notification tab? This is one theory that I think could be the issue. So would I do window.parent.parent.postmessage?

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Is there a way to post this on jsfiddle or codepen ?

Comment: `window.parent.opener.postMessage` if it's a i-frame within a popup

Comment: I will try to get a code pen out